# Recipient view not merged

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope from a template and then getting the URL for the recipient view.

During my request DocuSign sends an email to the recipient and that is merged and ready to sign but the signing url goes to an unmerged version of the document that cannot be signed.

I dont really want the email sent, I just want to redirect the customer straight into the signing session.

What am I missing here?

ENVELOPE CREATION REQUEST:

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Agreement",
  "templateId": "xxx",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "johndoe@inter.net",
      "name": "john doe",
      "roleName": "Customer",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Name",
            "value": "john doe"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "Date",
            "value": "1/18/2019"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "envelopeId": "yyy",
  "uri": "/envelopes/yyy",
  "statusDateTime": "2019-01-18T19:45:04.2870000Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
```

RECIPIENT VIEW REQUEST:

```
{
  "userName": "john doe",
  "email": "johndoe@inter.net",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "returnUrl": "http://www.inter.net/docusign.asp?Status=complete"
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/StartInSession.aspx?t=zzzz"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please "check" (Accept) the best answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indicate that you want to use an embedded signing ceremony for the template role, add the `clientUserId` attribute to the `templateRole` object.

Example of doing this: line 203 of the [Number 17 example workflow (for PHP)](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/EG017SetTemplateTabValues.php). This example workflow is also available for [Node.js](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/examples/eg017SetTemplateTabValues.js).

For a general example of using embedded signing, see example workflow 1 of the [eg-03 series](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03) of example launchers--see the list of repositories at the bottom of the page.